# Правопис префіксів з- та с- у словах створити/зтворити, спекти/зпекти, сфотографувати/зфотографувати?

Tags: правопис, префікс

Більшість подібних слів мають префікс `з-`: *здолати, зморити, з'їсти*.

Але деякі слова використовують префікс `с-`: *сфотографувати, створити, спекти, сховати*.

Часто в Інтернеті можна зустріти [*зфотографувати*](https://tsn.ua/politika/biyci-aydaru-pokazali-sviy-pobut-na-luganschini-portret-banderi-i-ukrayinska-simvolika-na-kamuflyazhi-359720.html), [*зпекти*](https://tsn.ua/ukrayina/u-pravoslavnih-rozpochavsya-strasniy-tizhden.html) тощо.

Яким є правопис цих двох префіксів?

Comment: З глухими приголосними пишемо префікс С-,  з дзвінкими - пишемо префікс З-.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Поточне

> <sub>Правопис 2019</sub>
>
> **ПРАВОПИС ПРЕФІКСІВ**
>
> [**§ 31. *З-* (*ІЗ-*, *ЗІ-*)**](//mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=25)
>
> 1. Префікс **з-** перед буквами на позначення глухих приголосних **к**, **п**, **т**, **ф**, **х** переходить у **с-**: *сказа́ти, спалахну́ти, стовкти́, сфотографува́ти, схили́ти*. Перед усіма іншими буквами пишемо **з** (зрідка **із**): *зба́вити, звести́, зжи́тися, ззирну́тися, зсади́ти, зціпи́ти, зчепи́ти, зши́ток; ізжо́вкнути, ізно́в, ізсере́дини*.

Це правило також відоме як *кафе птах*. Що в свою чергу, схоже, основане на:

> <sub>[Правопис 1928](//r2u.org.ua/data/other/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81-1928.pdf#page=15)</sub>
>
> **Б. Приростки — прийменники**
>
> **§ 19**. Щодо правопису й уживання приростків та прийменників, то треба
> додержуватися таких правил:
>
> 2. Приросток **з-** (або **із-** — див. § 10<sub>2</sub> Примітка) перед глухими приголосними **к**, **п**, **т**, **х** змінюється на **с-** (**іс-**): *сказа́ти*, *спита́ти* (*іспитати́*), *стули́ти, схил, схо́дити* і т. ін.: перед усіма іншими приголосними приросток **з-** (**із-**) не змінюється: *зба́вити, зве́сти́, зжа́литися, зчарува́ти, зціди́ти, зшива́ти, зсади́ти, зщу́литись, зформува́ти* і т. ін.

Де ± все таке саме, але без **ф**. Тож якщо хтось послїдовно так пише, скорїш за всього є прихильником цього правопису, що [відомий](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81) як *харківський*, *класичний* чи *скрипниківка*.

## Брати́ *с-* і *з-*

Саме по собі правило, на перший погляд, ґрунтує ся на — досить поширеному мовному явищї — [асімілації](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D1%96_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%B2_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96#%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85) за якістю звука, а саме дзвінкістю і глухістю, котре проявляє ся якраз на стиках з префіксом, бо в гинших місцях за глухістю вже не дуже, хиба що в говірках. Або так ма̀ло бути би, нп. за цим правилом маємо *зціпи́ти*, хоча за сучасною вимовою цїлком собі [[сц`і́пи<sup>е</sup>ти<sup>е</sup>](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%B7%D1%86%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8)].

Правопис, що відомий як [желехівка](//zbruc.eu/node/66463), *частково* враховує такий ніянс:

> *Приставку* **з** треба писати **с**, де она як **с** вимовляє ся (перед **п**, **т**, **к**, **ф**, **с**, **ш**, **ч**, **ц**, **щ**, **х**), н. пр. *спечи, сперти* (*зіпру*), *сходи, скрутити, сшити, счезнути, счорнїти, сцїдити, сфальшувати, ссїсти ся*. Але: *щастє, щасливий*.

Тобто перед кожним глухим приголосним пишемо якраз **с**. Чому *частково*? Згадане *але* в правилї вже указує на проблему: приголосні можуть уподібнювати ся і за місцьом твору, тобто згадані *счезнути* насправдї це *шчезнути*, а *зжитися* — *жжитися*. Так, *зчеплення* [[шче́пле<sup>и</sup>н`:а](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%B7%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F)] і *щеплення* [[шче́пле<sup>и</sup>н`:а](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F/%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F)] за чиною правовимовою мають цїлком однакову вимову.

Чому так не пишемо зараз? Перша [причина], українська не знає записи *сч* і *шч*, котрі автоматично стають буквою *щ*. Друга, українська не підпадає під відоме гасло *пиши як чуєш*, а ся намагає рівноважити між морфемікою і фонетікою, і можливо бігзна чим ще. І можлива третя, що впливає на другу, ґрафеміка — сучасна кірілиця, котра насправдї — ще один відомий міт — не зовсїм створена для словянських мов, пак сучасних, а є просто майже грубим переносом ґрецької абетки до словянських мов; або сталістю звичая. Нп. польська має подібне правило, але воно частково охопює і уподобу за мякістю:

> [**13.1.1. Pisownia przedrostka *z-* (*z-*, *s-*, *ś-*)**](//sjp.pwn.pl/zasady/35-13-1-1-Pisownia-przedrostka-z-z-s-s;629346)
>
> […] **ś-** piszemy przed połączeniem liter **ci** (oznaczającym spółgłoskę **ć** lub połączenie głosek **ći**), np. *ściąć, ściągnąć, ścichnąć, ściec, ścieniać, ścierpieć, ściosać, ścisnąć, ściszać*. […]

Тому якщо брати умовну латінське письмо, то правило могло би мати відповідні букви: **s**, **z**, **š** i **ž**. Навіщо гадати, якщо можна поглянути на дійсний приклад, а саме хорвацький правопис, котрий має *окремі* роздїли про…

Уподобу за звучністю:

> [**3.2.1. Jednačenje po zvučnosti**](http://pravopis.hr/pravilo/jednacenje-po-zvucnosti/6/)
>
> […] *beskofeinski* (< *bez* + *kofeinski*), *bespravni* (< *bez* + *pravni*), *golupčić* (< *golub* + *čić*), *otpasti* (< *od* + *pasti*), *pothodnik* (< *pod* + *hodnik*), *potpaliti* (< *pod* + *paliti*), *prethoditi* (< *pred* + *hoditi*), *pretklijetka* (< *pred* + *klijetka*), *pretkutnjak* (< *pred* + *kutnjak*), *pretpotopni* (< *pred* + *potopni*), *pretprijamni* (< *pred* + *prijamni*), *pretprijava* (< *pred* + *prijava*), *pretpristupni* (< *pred* + *pristupni*), *ropstvo* (< *rob* + *stvo*), *smećkast* (< *smeđ* + *kast*) […]

І за творбою:

> [**3.2.2. Jednačenje po mjestu tvorbe**](http://pravopis.hr/pravilo/jednacenje-po-mjestu-tvorbe/7/)
>
> […] *iščeprkati* (*iz* + *čeprkati*), *iščupati* (*iz* + *čupati*), […] *osnalažljiv* (*snalaz* + *ljiv*) […]

## А чи крівні?

Нп. вже знаємо, що *в(-)* може мати різну вимову в залежностї сусїдних звуків і навіть окремо записувати ся як *у(-)*. Але також відомо, що заміна часом неможлива — нп. *вдача ~ удача* — через різне походження приросктів, декотрі словянські мови досї чїтко розрізняють їх.

Приросток *роз-*, котрий в українській незмінний, лише підживює недовіру. Як не дивно, але етімолоґічний словник наводе тут подібну обставину:

> [**З**](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%B7#6439) (прийменник з род. в. для введення назв предметів, на поверхні яких знаходиться початковий пункт руху, дії)
>
> - прасловʼянська sъ, sъ(n)‹ *sъn›n;
> - зіставляється з латинським com «з», cum, давньокімерійським cant, ірландським cét «тс.», грецьким kατά (‹k ̑n̥-ta) «вниз, вздовж»;
>   поширена думка про етимологічну тотожність з<sup>1</sup> і з<sup>3</sup> (Skok III 179–180; Fraenkel AfSlPh 39, 89; Vondrák I 163, 418) натрапляє на труднощі семантичного характеру;
> - індоєвропейська. *k ̑оn;
> - в українській, як і в деяких інших слов’янських мовах, прасловʼянське *sъn збіглося фонетично з прасловʼянським iz;
>   російська, *с, со, с-, со-*, білоруська *з, са, з-, с, са-*, давньоруська *съ, съ(н)-*, польська верхньо-, нижньолужицька *z, ze, z-, ze-, s-*, чеська *s, se, s-, se-, z-*, словацька *s, so, s-, z-*, болгарська, македонська *c-*, сербохорватська *с, са, с-, са, з-*, словенська *s, se, z, ž, s-, z-*, старословʼянська *съ, съ(n-)*;

> [**З**](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%B7#6440) (прийменник з род. в. для введення назв предметів, усередині яких знаходиться початковий пункт руху, дії)
>
> - прасловʼянська iz, iz (‹*jьz);
> - споріднене з литовським ìš «із», [ìž], латиською iz, пруським is, is «тс.», албанським ith «за, позаду», латинським ex «із», грецьким ἐξ, ἐκ, галлським ex, ірландським ess;
> - індоєвропейська *eg’hs або *ek ̑(s);
> - в українській, як і в деяких інших слов’янських мовах, прасловʼянська *iz* фонетично збіглося з прасловʼянським **sъn*;
> - російська *из, из-*, білоруська *з, са*, давньоруська *изъ, из(ъ)-*, польська, верхньо-, нижньолужицька *z, ze*, чеська *z, ze, z-*, словацька *z, zo, z*, болгарська, сербохорватська *из, из-*, македонська [*из*] «крізь; по», *из-* «ви-», словенська *iz, iz*, старословʼянська *из, из-*;

Тобто якщо людина пише безпомилково і керує ся етімолоґічними засадами, а не фонетічними, то умовно *спекти* і *(і)зпекти* можуть мати різні смисли. Якщо несвідомо, але є закономірність, то може бути впливом рідної [говірки](http://erpub.chnpu.edu.ua:8080/jspui/bitstream/123456789/4565/1/%D0%9E%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%20%E2%80%93%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%96%D1%87.pdf), що зберегла певний вигляд і вимову приростка, нп.:

> Окремі лексеми Озерянської діалектної мікросистеми мають вузькорегіональний характер: […] *ізко́чуvалисʹ* – спускалися; *іж:арит'*– засмажити; *ізvарит'* – зварити; *ізпекти* – спекти […]